# Ambiguous reference to member subscript in Alamofire

Tags: alamofire, swift3

```
Alamofire.request(videosUrl!).responseJSON { response in
        if response.result.value != nil {

            let json = response.data

            do {

                let readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json!, options: .mutableContainers) as? JSONStandard

                if let items = readableJSON {

                    for i in 0..<items.count {

                        let item = items[i] <<< ERROR HERE

                        ...REST OF CODE HERE
                    }
                }    

             } catch {
                 print(error)
             }
         }
     }
```

I also have a typealias set:

```
typealias JSONStandard = [String:AnyObject]
```

My question is why am I getting the 'Ambiguous reference to member subscript' error? All I am trying to do is access the correct part of the array.

Comment: I am following an example from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjsxG07haJI) to the letter adapted to my needs and it works for him? See 21:27 for the almost complete code.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens, because subscript method of `Dictionary` (which is yours `JSONStandard`) requires:

1) `String` as a key parameter, but you passing `i` which has `Int` type. And according to the example your code is based on you probably should replace

```
if let items = readableJSON {
...
}
```

with

```
if let tracks = readableJSON["tracks"] as? JSONStandard {
      if let items = tracks["items"] as? [JSONStandard] {
          ...
      }
}
```

In this case `items` becomes an `Array` which uses `Int` index in subscript method.

2) or because `Dictionary` is also a collection with index type `DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>` subscript also can expect `DictionaryIndex<String, AnyObject>`. In your case you can replace

```
for i in 0..<items.count {
```

with

```
for i in items.indices {
```

or even with

```
for (_, item) in items {
```

The solution you chose depends on the structure of your **JSON**