# Ambiguous use of 'subscript' in swift 3 using xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10

I am getting issues of Ambiguous use of 'subscript' as per mentioned in Screen Shot that is attached here. I am trying to use Alamofire for api calling. is there any issues of xcode 8 ? i am using swift 3 with xcode 8 in IOS 10. Will anybody please help me to fix this issue?
[image]

Comment: You have to cast `track["items"]` to something reasonable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39531656/2083655

Comment: i am not getting from given references that what i have to do.

Comment: replace `if let items = tracks["items"]` with `if let items = tracks["items"] as? [JSONStandard]`

Comment: replace if let items = tracks["items"] with if let items = tracks["items"] as? [JSONStandard] gets error.

Comment: It comes only in Device not in Simulator

Comment: What's the error when you use `if let items = tracks["items"] as? [JSONStandard]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if let tracks = readableJSON["tracks"] as? JSONStandard
{
  if let items = tracks["items"] as? NSArray
  {
     for i in 0..<items.count
     {
        let item = items[i] as? JSONStandard
        let name = item?["name"] as! String
        names.append(name)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
     }               
   }
}
```

I got my answer with line 
`if let items = tracks["items"] as? NSArray` instead of `if let items = tracks["items"]`

Here Simulator takes types itself and for device we have to specify data type as i have writtern `as? NSArray` for `items`

Comment: As the array contains JSON dictionaries anyway why not `[JSONStandard]` rather than `NSArray`?